# Edit assigned compatible configurations for agents in teamcity rest api

Tags: teamcity, teamcity-9.0

Is it possible to edit assigned compatible configurations for agents in teamcity rest api?
(I am using 9.0.2).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes - you can add or remove any project to any agent pool through the REST API:

> POST the plain text (name) to
>   http://teamcity.url/app/rest/agentPools/id:XXX/projects
>
> Delete a project from a pool: DELETE
>   http://teamcity.url/app/rest/agentPools/id:XXX/projects/id:YYY

**See the docs [here](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD9/REST+API#RESTAPI-AssigningProjectstoAgentPools).**

An agent pool is just a n:m mapping concept in TeamCity that allows you to specify which agents can run which projects - it allows for more flexibility than directly assigning agents to projects.

Comment: Thanks! I was looking at an old documentation :\